# Object creation design pattern in vtk

Tags: design-patterns, vtk

Why do vtk classes derived from `vtkObjectBase` have protected constructors and objects must be instantiated in the heap via a static method called `New`?

Why was this design chosen and what are its main advantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern is called "factory method". Here are the arguments for it, ordered by importance descending (in my opinion; I was not there when these design decisions in VTK were being made).

- Allowing for polymorhic behavior, and thus cross-platformness. When you do

`vtkRenderWindow* rw = vtkRenderWindow::New();`

You are actually creating some derived object, e.g. vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow on Linux/X11 or vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWindow on Windows. The toolkit figures it out with various system checks (mostly at configure time), and injects a factory for the object creation, which returns object of correct type. This whole machinery is transparent to the user, who uses the objects via the abstract base class pointer only.

- Protected ctors forbid allocating the objects on the stack, which enforces the memory management model (by Un/Register()-ing, i.e. reference counting within vtkObject).
- Syntactic consistency allows use with templates, such as vtkSmartPointer.

There are probably other reasons that I cannot think of right now.

Hope this helps,

Miro

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mirni. Regarding the second point, I would argue that preventing stack allocation is not really an advantage.

Comment: @iglesias In this case, stack allocation is undesirable. VTK is intended for visualization of large datasets and it would be bad to perform allocation of large arrays on the stack. The libraries are designed to construct pipelines that usually live longer than the stack scope, and the dataset classes consist of multiple instances of multiple classes — which would be difficult to manage if any of them were allowed to disappear without their owners knowing or responding.